# download a pdf with filesaver.js and blob

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I'm trying to download a file with `Filesaver.js`. And when I try to do this with  csv, it works fine. But I need to download a pdf now.

How can I do that?
I use `Filesaver.js` with a blob object, my code looks something like this:

```
var filename = "myfile.csv";
var s = "my csv text content";
var blob = new Blob([s], {type "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
var filesaver = saveAs(blob,filename);
```

I'd like to know what kind of data type should I pass to the blob onject, when I'd like to download the pdf.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/pdf;charset=utf-8"});
 var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
```

Both are ok,but header should be

```
{responseType:"arraybuffer"}
```

Comment: thanks this is works for me,.. but how to get the filename?

Answer (score 2):

Data type should be `application/pdf` of course.

The content should be on `base64` so the blob should start with

```
data:application/pdf;base64,
```

As you can see in the [jspdf](/questions/tagged/jspdf) library source code.

Enjoy the [demo](http://plnkr.co/5NonsdQ23nXwFchV01sB).

Comment: Provided sample doesn't use FileSaver as requested.

Comment: It does, verified on Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

PDF is completely another format and FileSaver's only mission is saving files.

You can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library to do that. This is how you could use it in your case:

```
var filename = "myfile.csv";
var s = "my csv text content";

var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.text(10, 10, s);
pdf.save(filename.replace(".csv", ".pdf"));
```