# Download PDF file using FileSaver is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, download, filesaver.js

```
  const response =  await  axios.request(options);   
  var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob,"helloworld.pdf");
```

FileSaver.saveAs(blob,"helloworld.txt") file is working but when i try to download pdf file it download blank pdf file.
Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: will this help you ? [similar Q asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494377/download-a-pdf-with-filesaver-js-and-blob)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing options when call api, you should add like this

```
{
  url: 'download/0QvXO3GJAyzkxAqY',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // Important
}
```

I mixed your question and my answer and it worked